# wrong output, can't understand why C

Tags: c, function

I am a beginner in C programming and I built a function that recieves the string `"HodHasharon,frozenYogurt,100"`. The function cuts the string into 3 pieces where every piece is a field of my `City` struct.

I want to put `"HodHasharon"` into
City `pcity.name` (name of the city), `"frozenYogurt"` into `pcity.popularFood` (popular food) and number of residents (`100`) into `pcity.residents`.

When i am debugging the output in my function the output is correct but when i print from the `main.c` I got a concatenated string.

For example, when I print `pcity.name` I get `"HodHashafrozenYod"` instead of `"HodHasharon"` but if I do printf at my function printf->name I get the correct output of `"HodHasharon"`

What am I doing wrong?

struct of City:

```
typedef struct City
{
    char *name;
    char * popluarFood;
    int numberOfPeople;

} City;
```

the function:

```
City * cutCityData (char *singleLine)
{
    City* pcity=(City*)malloc(sizeof(City));
    int firstIndex=1;
    int endIndex=1;
    int checkItarion=0;
    while(endIndex<strlen(singleLine))
    {//while
        while (singleLine[endIndex] != ',')
        {//while2
            endIndex++;
        }//while2
        checkItarion++;
        char cityDetails[endIndex - firstIndex +1];
        memcpy(cityDetails,&singleLine[firstIndex], endIndex);
        cityDetails[endIndex - firstIndex] = '\0';
        if (checkItarion == 1) {
            pcity->name = (char *) malloc(cityDetails);
            strcpy(&(pcity->name), cityDetails);
            endIndex++;
            firstIndex = endIndex;
        }
        if (checkItarion == 2) {
            pcity->popluarFood = (char *) malloc(cityDetails);
            strcpy(&(pcity->popluarFood), cityDetails);
            endIndex++;
            firstIndex=endIndex;
            break;
        }
    }//while
    char cityDetails[strlen(singleLine) - firstIndex + 1];
    memcpy(cityDetails, &singleLine[firstIndex], sizeof(singleLine-1));
    int resdints=atoi(cityDetails);
    pcity->numberOfPeople=resdints;
    return pcity;
    }
```

from main:

```
City* pCity=cutCityData(singLine);
printf("%s\n", &(pCity->name));
```

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips on debugging your code. If you still need help, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: `&(pCity->name)` should just be `pCity->name`

Comment: You can use `strchr()` to search for a `,` instead of writing your own loop.

Comment: Array indexes start at `0`. Why are you setting `firstIndex` to `1`?

Comment: pCity-> without & i got : Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Comment: because i dont wan to calculate the "\t"

Comment: The question doesn't say anything about `\t`.

Comment: " HodHasharon,frozenYogurt,100" this is the input , the first char is "\t"

Comment: Please refer to the first comment. Read both the "how to debug" and the MCVE link. Really. Do. Most problems go away on their own with those two pieces of advice alone...

Answer (score 1):

`&(pcity->name)` is the address of the pointer variable. You want to copy the string to the memory that it points to, not copy over the pointer. So change:

```
strcpy(&(pcity->name), cityDetails);
```

to

```
strcpy(pcity->name, cityDetails);
```

You're also giving the wrong argument to `malloc()`. `cityDetails` is an array, but the argument should be the number of bytes you want to allocate. So change

```
pcity->name = (char *) malloc(cityDetails);
```

to:

```
pcity->name = malloc(strlen(cityDetails) + 1);
```

These changes also need to be made for the code that fills in `pcity->popularFood` as well.

This is wrong:

```
memcpy(cityDetails, &singleLine[firstIndex], sizeof(singleLine-1));
```

`singleLine` is a pointer, so `sizeof(singleLine-1)` is the number of bytes in a pointer, not the length of the string. This should be:

```
memcpy(cityDetails, &singleLine[firstIndex], endIndex + 1);
```